# Mypy accepts an incompatible type in __init__ override

Tags: python, types, mypy, python-typing, liskov-substitution-principle

I have the following `Foo` base class, and `Bar` that inherits from it:

```py
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, x: int) -> None:
        self._x = x

    def do(self, x: int) -> None:
        pass


class Bar(Foo):
    pass
```

If I override `Foo.do` in `Bar`, and change the type of the `x` parameter for something incompatible (that is, not more generic than `int`), then Mypy returns an error - which is of course what I expect.

```py
class Bar(Foo):
    def do(self, x: str) -> None:
        pass
```

Error:

```
test.py:10: error: Argument 1 of "do" is incompatible with supertype "Foo"; supertype defines the argument type as "int"
test.py:10: note: This violates the Liskov substitution principle
test.py:10: note: See https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/common_issues.html#incompatible-overrides
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

However, if I override `__init__` with an incompatible type for the argument, then Mypy accepts it:

```py
class Bar(Foo):
    def __init__(self, x: str) -> None:
        self._x = 12
```

Mypy output:

```
Success: no issues found in 1 source file
```

It looks to me that overriding `__init__` with incompatible types violates the LSP as well, since code like `foo = Foo(12)` does not type-check if we replace `Foo` with `Bar`.

Why does Mypy accept that I override `__init__` with an incompatible type? Is `__init__` treated differently from other methods?
Also, is Mypy right in doing so? Am I correct that this last `Bar` class violates the LSP?

Comment: Note if you actually use `self._x = x` or `super().__init__(x)` in `Bar`, that _is_ caught. Whether it breaches the LSP is an interesting one - the _class_ `Bar` can't be swapped in for `Foo`, but their _instances_ are compatible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Liskov Substitution Principle is not generally considered to apply to constructor methods. If we were to treat constructor methods as part of an object's interface, it would make inheritance systems extremely difficult to manage in many situations, and lead to a whole host of other complications. See [this question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/431549/the-liskov-substitution-principle-and-python) I posed on Software Engineering a while back.

The situation is complicated somewhat, however, by the fact that `__init__` *isn't* really a constructor method (that would be `__new__`) — it's an initialiser method, and it can be called multiple times on the same instance. It just "happens" to be the case that the initialiser method nearly always has the same signature as the constructor method.

Because of the way `__init__` can be called multiple times on the same instance, just like a "normal" method that would be considered part of an object's interface, there's currently [active discussion](https://bugs.python.org/issue44807) among the core devs regarding whether `__init__` methods *should* be considered part of an object's interface in some respects.

**To conclude:** `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Python is an *extremely* dynamic language, and that means reasoning about its type system can often be kind of strange.

Comment: scala's worth considering here. Constructors, as well as the `apply` method on `object`s, which are both akin to python's `__init__` for this discussion, are also unconstrained

Comment: @joel could you say a little more/send some links my way? I know zilch about Scala, but it sounds interesting :)

Comment: `object` isn't too important, but [here](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/scala-book/abstract-classes.html)'s how it works for abstract classes. I now remember that you can't extend concrete classes in scala. In that example they retain the signature, but you can add parameters (like I do [here](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/hQB74N0QQAGwGC4afFRQwA))

Comment: as an aside "Because of the way `__init__` can be called multiple times on the same instance". While this is true, when would you call it twice?

Comment: @joel I actually have implemented a context manager that uses precisely this pattern in a project I'm working on at the moment. The object's `__init__` is called in both the `__exit__` and `__call__` methods of the context manager. The `__call__` method calls `__init__` to alter the internal state of the context manager every time I enter a `with` statement, and the `__exit__` method calls `__init__` to reset the internal state to the "default" settings every time I leave the `with` block.

Comment: @joel for example https://gist.github.com/b1682100a9cc80e07407aa20a630bfff

Comment: "The Liskov Substitution Principle is not generally considered to apply to constructor methods." Would you have references to support this claim? I'd love to read more about it!

Comment: @Rightleg I think I'd just refer you to the discussion I had on Software Engineering — there were loads of really great answers to the question I asked there, that answered that question https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/431549/the-liskov-substitution-principle-and-python

Comment: @Rightleg But to take the example I open with in my Software Engineering question: if LSP did apply to constructor methods, *literally every class implemented in Python that accepts parameters in its `__init__` method would break LSP*, since all classes inherit from `object`, and `object` takes 0 parameters other than `self` in its `__init__` method.

Answer (score 2):

**Note** I'm really not sure about this. I'll let the voting judge.

**tl;dr** LSP doesn't apply to `__init__` in that way because it's not meant for use as a method on instances.

[LSP states](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle)

> Subtype Requirement: Let Q(t) be a property provable about objects t of type T. Then Q(s) should be true for objects s of type S where S is a subtype of T.

For `do`, we have

```
Q(x) = signature of x.do
t = Foo(...)
T = Foo
s = Bar(...)
S = Bar
```

and since `do` has the same signature for all instances of `Foo` (i.e. it's a provable property of objects t of T), this must also be true for objects of type `Bar`. However, for `__init__`, which is effectively a method on the class, we have

```
t = Foo
T = type[Foo]
s = Bar
S = type[Bar]
```

In this case, there's no provable property regarding `__init__` about objects t (i.e. classes) of type `type[Foo]`, as this includes *both* `Foo` and `Bar`, so LSP says nothing about the signature of `Bar`.