# Overriding __init__ method

Tags: python, oop, overriding, signature, init

I am confused about overriding. When we define a **init** method inside a class, is it really overriding the **init** method of the base "object" class?. As far as i know, The basic rule of overriding a method is that both overriding and overriden method should have the same signature. But in the example below, if we check the signatures of the **init** method of the object class and child class, its not equal.

```
from inspect import signature
class Child:
    def __init__(self, age):
        self.age = age
print(signature(Child.__init__) == object.__init__)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Method overriding, does signature matter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6034662/python-method-overriding-does-signature-matter)

Comment: Not exactly the same question, but the answers here are the answers to your question: [Mypy accepts an incompatible type in __init__ override](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69394820/12299000)

Comment: In a statically typed world, you are correct: the type of the override should be a subtype of the function being overriden. Python is *not* statically typed, though, and the signature of `object.__init__` long predates the addition of type hints to the language. Ideally, `object.__init__` might accept, but *ignore*, any arguments it receives.

Comment: Other concerns aside, `signature(Child.__init__) == object.__init__` doesn't actually compare the signatures.

Answer (score 0):

When you define an **__init__** method, you instruct Python how to instantiate the class. So you are overriding the **__init__** method of the base `object` class because now to instantiate a new object of class `Child` you will have to use your new **__init__** method.

In Python, the functions overridden in the subclasses don't need to have the same signatures as the functions in the parent class, as long as they respect the [Liskov Substitution Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle). This is not necessary for constructors though.